# mysqli prepared statement order by

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a friendship table called `friends` that looks like this:

```
id  | user1 | user2
------------------
1   | ab    | abc
2   | ab    | abcd
3   | aa    | ab
```

if `"ab"` and `"abc"` are in the same row it means that they're friends. Now, when a user, say `"ab"` logs in, he will see his friends' posts(posts of `'abc'`,`'abcd'`,and `'aa'`) Here is the php code:

```
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['username']; //$name=ab;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT location,postby,pid,likes,time FROM photos WHERE postby=? ORDER BY time");
    $query = $link->query("(select user2 from friends where user1='$name')union(select user1 from friends where user2='$name')");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $b = $row['user2'];
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $b);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $stmt->bind_result($location, $postby,$id,$likes,$time);
    $stmt->store_result();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
          //code to display picture
        }
   }
```

The problem is that the result is not really order by time. It will first display all posts by a user, and order that user's posts by time, then display posts of another user, and order that user's posts by time, but I want to order all the posts by time. How can I do that?

Comment: If you could print out the time field, show us the results you have from the query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the friends posts in one query.

Try the following:

```
$sql = 'SELECT location, postby, pid, likes, time 
    FROM photos 
    WHERE 
     postby IN (
       SELECT user2 FROM friends where user1=?
       UNION 
       SELECT user1 FROM friends where user2=?
     )
    ORDER BY time';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi, how can I use a prepared statement and bind parameters in this case?

Comment: Just as you do it with every other mysqli query. I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi I got "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean", which means the prepared statement returns false? Are you missing a close bracket or something? There are 3 close bracket but only 1 open bracket in your sql

Comment: Yes right, I copied those `)` from your query. No need to put the unioned selects in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you fetch the result in separate queries.

You should query all the user ids you want to show posts from('ab','abc','abcd',and 'aa' in your case), then do one query to get all the posts and order that result.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT location,postby,pid,likes,time FROM photos WHERE postby IN (?) ORDER BY time");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your date query is executed on each of your query. So first you try to get all the data of one user and then you orderby datetime. Then you find other user and orderby time.

It would be better if you would write a whole SQL statement with joins and then that statmenet make ordered.

Could you post the whole table and then I can write you a SQL query that would do a join based on users and order it by time.

Since this is a table for M:M could you post the whole picture of database design. Or at least the tables that are in a relationship.

Comment: do you mean you want see the design of the "photos" table?